# SceneKit SCNPhysicsVehicle wheels point toward centre of vehicle

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm trying to get the SceneKit Physics Vehicle [demonstration from WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SceneKitVehicle/Listings/SceneKitVehicle_AAPLGameViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014549-SceneKitVehicle_AAPLGameViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_7) working using Swift 2 and also the Scene Editor and .scnassets. I'm adapting [this port of the demo to Swift 1.](https://bitbucket.org/girobai/swiftscenekitvehicledemo/overview)

I've also been experimenting with some of the Model I/O functions, such as SkyBox and normal map generation.

Everything works fine, except that the wheels are rotated 180 degrees around their steering axes, so that the hubcaps point in towards the centre of the car:

[image: hubcaps pointing inward]
**Hubcaps pointing inwards**

The wheels spin in the right direction, and the car can be driven and steered fine, but it just looks very weird (and the left-right wheelbase is narrower than it should be).

If I comment out the SCNPhysicsVehicle and SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel code, so that it's just geometry with a physics body for the chassis, the geometry displays correctly, with the wheel hubs pointing outward:

[image: hubcaps pointing outward]
**Hubcaps pointing outwards**

I've tried rotating the wheelnodes using `wheelnode0.rotation` before defining the SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel, but it has no effect.

I tried reversing the wheel axles with `wheel0.axle = SCNVector3(x: 1,y: 0,z: 0)` and that makes the wheels face the right way, hubcap outwards, (and they still spin the right way), but the car moves backwards (ie the opposite direction to how the wheels are spinning).

It feels like something weird is going on with how axes are being translated, but I can't figure what it is. I've tried it with the original .dae model from the Apple demo, as well as converted to an .scn file. I've tried it inside and outside an .scnassets folder (in case it was something to do with scnassets auto correction of up axis). I tried inverting the wheel steering axes, but that just resulted in the wheels pointing up in the air.

Here's my vehicle creation function, with all the stuff I've tried commented out. Full repo is here: https://github.com/Utsira/SCNPhysicsVehicle-test. Can anyone see what's going wrong here? Thanks in advance.

```
func setupCar() -> SCNNode {
    let carScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/rc_car.scn") //rc_car.dae
    let chassisNode = carScene!.rootNode.childNodeWithName("rccarBody", recursively: true)!
    chassisNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 10, 30)
    //chassisNode.rotation = SCNVector4(0, 1, 0, CGFloat(M_PI))
    let body = SCNPhysicsBody.dynamicBody()
    body.allowsResting = false
    body.mass = 80
    body.restitution = 0.1
    body.friction = 0.5
    body.rollingFriction = 0
    chassisNode.physicsBody = body
    scnScene.rootNode.addChildNode(chassisNode)
     //getNode("rccarBody", fromDaePath: "rc_car.dae")
    let wheelnode0 = chassisNode
        .childNodeWithName("wheelLocator_FL", recursively: true)!
    let wheelnode1 = chassisNode
        .childNodeWithName("wheelLocator_FR", recursively: true)!
    let wheelnode2 = chassisNode
        .childNodeWithName("wheelLocator_RL", recursively: true)!
    let wheelnode3 = chassisNode
        .childNodeWithName("wheelLocator_RR", recursively: true)!

    //wheelnode0.geometry!.firstMaterial!.emission.contents = UIColor.blueColor()
    //        SCNTransaction.begin()
    //        wheelnode0.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, w: Float(M_PI)) //CGFloat(M_PI)
    //        wheelnode1.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, w: Float(M_PI))
    //        wheelnode2.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, w: Float(M_PI))
    //        wheelnode3.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 0, y: 1, z: 0, w: Float(M_PI))
    //        SCNTransaction.commit()
    //        wheelnode0.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(0, Float(M_PI), 0 )
    let wheel0 = SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel(node: wheelnode0)
    let wheel1 = SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel(node: wheelnode1)
    let wheel2 = SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel(node: wheelnode2)
    let wheel3 = SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel(node: wheelnode3)
    //        wheel0.steeringAxis = SCNVector3Make(0, -1, 1) //wheels point up in the air with 0,1,0
    //        wheel1.steeringAxis = SCNVector3Make(0, -1, 1)
    //        wheel2.steeringAxis = SCNVector3Make(0, -1, 1)
    //        wheel3.steeringAxis = SCNVector3Make(0, -1, 1)
    //        
    //        wheel0.axle = SCNVector3(x: 1,y: 0,z: 0) //wheels face and spin the right way, but car moves in opposite direction with 1,0,0
    //        wheel1.axle = SCNVector3(x: 1,y: 0,z: 0)
    //        wheel2.axle = SCNVector3(x: 1,y: 0,z: 0)
    //        wheel3.axle = SCNVector3(x: 1,y: 0,z: 0)
           // wheel0.steeringAxis = SCNVector3()
    //        var min = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
    //        var max = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
    //        wheelnode0.getBoundingBoxMin(&min, max: &max)
    //        let wheelHalfWidth = Float(0.5 * (max.x - min.x))
    //        var w0 = wheelnode0.convertPosition(SCNVector3Zero, toNode: chassisNode)
    //        w0 = w0 + SCNVector3Make(wheelHalfWidth, 0, 0)
    //        wheel0.connectionPosition = w0
    //        var w1 = wheelnode1.convertPosition(SCNVector3Zero, toNode: chassisNode)
    //        w1 = w1 - SCNVector3Make(wheelHalfWidth, 0, 0)
    //        wheel1.connectionPosition = w1
    //        var w2 = wheelnode2.convertPosition(SCNVector3Zero, toNode: chassisNode)
    //        w2 = w2 + SCNVector3Make(wheelHalfWidth, 0, 0)
    //        wheel2.connectionPosition = w2
    //        var w3 = wheelnode3.convertPosition(SCNVector3Zero, toNode: chassisNode)
    //        w3 = w3 - SCNVector3Make(wheelHalfWidth, 0, 0)
    //        wheel3.connectionPosition = w3

    vehicle = SCNPhysicsVehicle(chassisBody: chassisNode.physicsBody!,
                                wheels: [wheel0, wheel1, wheel2, wheel3])
    scnScene.physicsWorld.addBehavior(vehicle)
    return chassisNode

}
```

Comment: I drew on [this port of the WWDC demo to Swift 1](https://bitbucket.org/girobai/swiftscenekitvehicledemo/overview).  I couldn't get this working though, because it had too many incompatibilities with Swift 2.

Comment: Here's my repo: https://github.com/Utsira/SCNPhysicsVehicle-test

Comment: Actually, when I fire up the original Objective C version of the demo, it also has the hubcaps pointing inwards. :-( I'd still like to know though why the geometry of the wheels gets spun round like that when you define the node as a SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I Found A Solution:

(but not the solution I hoped for)

My fix was to adjust the connectionPosition of "FrontLeftWheel", so much to the right, that it took the role of "FrontRightWheel".

And "FrontRightWheel", so much to the left, that it took the role of "FrontLeftWheel".

I also did this for the back.


Basically, where you have:

```
SCNVector3Make(wheelHalfWidth, 0, 0)
```

I replaced it with:

```
SCNVector3Make(wheelHalfWidth * 5.2, 0, 0)
```

However, you may have to fool around with the number "5.2" to match up with your COLLADA (.dae).

### A Note:

Do Not forget to replace:

```
 vehicle = SCNPhysicsVehicle(chassisBody: chassisNode.physicsBody!,
                            wheels: [wheel0, wheel1, wheel2, wheel3])
```

With:

```
 vehicle = SCNPhysicsVehicle(chassisBody: chassisNode.physicsBody!,
                            wheels: [wheel1, wheel0, wheel3, wheel2])
```

This way, when you use car.wheels[0].
You get the wheel you are expecting

Comment: Thanks for this! I did wonder whether the "hub caps pointing in" thing was because the wheels were swapped round, so I coloured the front left wheel blue to make sure it still was in the front left position. One thing, are you sure you don't mean "-5.2"?

Comment: I also tried raising the wheels up. I found that "up" on the left side of the vehicle is negative Y `SCNVector3Make(wheelHalfWidth * - 5.2, -wheelHalfWidth, 0)`, while on the right side it's positive Y. It's a cludge, but it seems to work, vehicle is drivable and steerable (and now has better grip with the wider wheel base).

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer, though for me it was "-5.2". Repo has been updated. Thank you Pro Blaster!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are not setting the connection positions for each wheel. Apple's default ObjectiveC code is tricky to translate to swift.

```
wheel0.connectionPosition = SCNVector3FromFloat3(SCNVector3ToFloat3([wheel0Node convertPosition:SCNVector3Zero toNode:chassisNode]) + (vector_float3){wheelHalfWidth, 0.0, 0.0});
wheel1.connectionPosition = SCNVector3FromFloat3(SCNVector3ToFloat3([wheel1Node convertPosition:SCNVector3Zero toNode:chassisNode]) - (vector_float3){wheelHalfWidth, 0.0, 0.0});
wheel2.connectionPosition = SCNVector3FromFloat3(SCNVector3ToFloat3([wheel2Node convertPosition:SCNVector3Zero toNode:chassisNode]) + (vector_float3){wheelHalfWidth, 0.0, 0.0});
wheel3.connectionPosition = SCNVector3FromFloat3(SCNVector3ToFloat3([wheel3Node convertPosition:SCNVector3Zero toNode:chassisNode]) - (vector_float3){wheelHalfWidth, 0.0, 0.0});
```

These four lines translate (ignoring the repetition)

```
let wheel0Position = wheel0Node.convertPosition(SCNVector3Zero, to: chassisNode)
let vector0Float3 = vector_float3(wheel0Position.x, wheel0Position.y, wheel0Position.z) + vector_float3(wheelHalfWidth, 0,0)
wheel0.connectionPosition = SCNVector3(vector0Float3.x, vector0Float3.y, vector0Float3.z)

let wheel1Position = wheel1Node.convertPosition(SCNVector3Zero, to: chassisNode)
let vector1Float3 = vector_float3(wheel1Position.x, wheel1Position.y, wheel1Position.z) - vector_float3(wheelHalfWidth, 0,0)
wheel1.connectionPosition = SCNVector3(vector1Float3.x, vector1Float3.y, vector1Float3.z)

let wheel2Position = wheel2Node.convertPosition(SCNVector3Zero, to: chassisNode)
let vector2Float3 = vector_float3(wheel2Position.x, wheel2Position.y, wheel2Position.z) + vector_float3(wheelHalfWidth, 0,0)
wheel2.connectionPosition = SCNVector3(vector2Float3.x, vector2Float3.y, vector2Float3.z)

let wheel3Position = wheel3Node.convertPosition(SCNVector3Zero, to: chassisNode)
let vector3Float3 = vector_float3(wheel3Position.x, wheel3Position.y, wheel3Position.z) - vector_float3(wheelHalfWidth, 0,0)
wheel3.connectionPosition = SCNVector3(vector3Float3.x, vector3Float3.y, vector3Float3.z)
```

By adding or substracting vector_float3, the wheels are positioned in the right place.

Also, bear in mind that you can't scale the node in the scene or weird things may happen.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue, my solution was to rotate all wheel nodes so the Y axis pointed down. I figured gravity is a downward force.